# DKIM temperror with hotmail due to nameserver records pointing to same server IP?

Tags: email, dkim

When I send emails to Hotmail I always seem to get DKIM temperrors. Only for hotmail. All other providers give pass.
Now I'm wondering it this could have something to do with both nameservers for the domain pointing to the same server IP.
Note that my emails seem to get delivered *however* some seem to go to spam (for no obvious reason). We're not sending mass emails/mailing campaigns.

example.com: my domain (IP is x.y.z.w of this server)
ns1.anotherexample.com: point to x.y.z.w (so my DNS server)
ns2.anotherexample.com: point to x.y.z.w (so my DNS server)

Both ns IPs are the same. Also note the nameserver records are from dynu. However no dynamic IPs are being used anywhere.

I've did a lot of different tests (for both DKIM, SPF, DMARC, A record, PTR record, MX record, postfix settings ...) and all seem to be ok.

Would this interfere with how hotmail treats my email?
I wouldn't think so but there's I can't seem to get any consistent behavior from their mailservers.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I find Microsoft domains to be incredibly hostile to email. I have had so much legitimate mail from old domains with unique IPs that I just ignore problems from MS and tell people on those domains they should find a new service. I know this doesn't answer your question, but you may want to budget your time accordingly, and move on to battles you can win.

Comment: I **completely** agree with that attitude. But if your potential customers are using hotmail saying they should use another service is not an option. So they send you an email, you answer, it goes to spam or never arrives (for no reason as the message is accepted for delivery). If you have 1000s of leads you can use this strategy but if you are working on bigger things with only multiple leads this is not an option. Hotmail should actually be banned.

Comment: Microsofts services are also incredible inconsistent. I find that the same mails (from a mailinglist) are rejected when sent to a hotmail address but accepted when sent to a live.com or outlook.com address. You would think that microsoft has the same procedure for all their domains, but obviously that is not the case.

Comment: Then you're still very lucky as this is pretty consistent. I've seen mail arriving to the hotmail account, getting mail back from the hotmail user, then replying to that and this last mail never arrives (is also accepted for delivery) but never gets there. Retry a week later and it does get delivered. Or it is delivered for a@hotmail.com but not for b@hotmail.com. So it still depends on which server the mailbox is located.